# Resizing columns in adobe flex AdvancedDataGrid

Tags: apache-flex, resize, advanceddatagrid

I'm using an AdvancedDataGrid without the header row (AdvancedDataGrid.showHeaders="false"), my AdvancedDataGrid has 2 columns, where the first one will show a hierarchical data (tree).
The tree may be very long and very deep or may contain a long string in the node label so the user will not be able to see the whole vale of the tree node, I want to be able to resize the column using the vertical separator of the gris (the one displayed/separates between columns) or to be able to define a horizontal scroll bar only for the first column!
How can I accomplish this?!....Any idea ?!

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the Advanced Datagrid tag's attribute 'wordWrap="true"'.